# single page application with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, singlepage

I just saw this video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs8-l2Uo1cQ

And i got cuple of questions. I am about to develop quite a complex web site with alot of reporting data(like diagrams) and more, before i saw this video i was certanly sure that i am going to use MVC 4 forms authentication solution. But right now i am conserned. Is singel Page application suitebale for complex solution? or is it only suitable for simple portfolio websites?

No hate, its probably a stupid and obviouse answer to this question, but i am new to SPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. ASP.NET MVC 4 suitable for complex single-page solutions. I personally have used it when building large financial applications.

You might also want to check out Web API (which comes bundled as part of ASP.NET MVC 4) which is even better suited for single-page applications.

Comment: i see that upshot.js is no longer under development, which tools have u used instead?

Comment: @Timsen - The only library we used was MooTools. Everything else was hand rolled. I suggest taking a look at http://www.asp.net/single-page-application for ideas.

Comment: upshot.js is officially dead check @breeze.js