# Navigation between controllers without loading the whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

There is a way to load the contents of a page by navigating from one controller to another controller without loading the whole page and without changing the URL?
I need it for example to keep title, user information, etc, without having to load them each time.

Comment: SPA is your friend: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: Mohammed is correct. Single page application is what you need. Previous version of asp.net allowed for ajax "partial loads", but Single Page Applications are truly better suited for it. Brush up on your javascript! For reference: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: This would develop MVC3?
It can to fit on the existing project?

Comment: @Refael I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919981/single-page-application-with-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

youll need a single page application. you might want to use a framework for that.

[Angular JS](http://angularjs.org/)
or [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com/)  and you have many more.

you can do it alone, but it can be complicated.